# "rails server" command is not getting recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I am new to rails and am following the tutorial posted on the ROR website. Everything is working fine until I try and load up my rails application on the localhost. Every time  enter `$ rails server` I get a long list of possible commands and functions. When I check my `localhost:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000`, nothing seems to be connected.

Upon digging deeper, I have tried almost everything everyone else has tried. I am running the command in the same path as my new rails application. Furthermore, when I enter in nonsense after the `$ rails` command I get the same list of possible commands and functions. So I get the feeling that rails is not recognizing the `server` command.

Here are my versions:

- Ruby 1.9.3 p374
- Rails 3.2.11

Why isn't the `server` command recognized?

Comment: I think you are not in right directory.

Comment: What is the output when you run `which rails` and `ls -l config/routes.rb`?

Comment: Exit and restart terminal. Go to correct directory - verify with `pwd`. Then run `rails -v` and `ruby -v`. What is the result? Read the outputs *very* carefully, line by line and tell us of any errors. Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: are u getting any error, if so could u post the error log here

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to move to the project directory and install bundle with the following command:

```
bundle install
```

Then start the server:

```
rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. `rails server` or simply `rails s` only works when you are in the right directory.

Type `pwd` (present working directory) to see where you currently are.
Type `cd` and the rest of the direction to the correct directory.
(for example, "cd workspace/learn-rails")
Type `rails server` or `rails s`.
Check http://localhost:3000.

Comment: `rails s -d` doesn't seem to work when `rails s` does for a particular working directory, is there a way to specify the directory as a parameter somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Please exit from terminal and then restart the terminal.

Then check the directory path i.e just type `pwd` it will show the current directory path.

And if directory is correct on try again running command like `bundle install` & `rails server`

I think this should be work.